# How much dragonglass damage must a wight or White Walker suffer before dying?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In season 8 episode 3 of *Game of Thrones*, we see

> a giant wight.

This creature seems to be very hard to kill. In fact, someone has to stab one of its eyes in order to kill it.

As far as I know, this injury may or may not have been deadly to a living human being.

So, how much of an injury is needed in order to kill a wight?

Would stabbing the creature in the feet (with dragonglass) work? If you stab the belly, is there a minimal "depth" you need to go in?